# How to filter data based on client permissions instead of broadcasting?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am learning SignalR. Something I can't wrap my head around is this:

SignalR allows us to apply authentication/authorization using [Authorize] attribute. This works to prevent clients from calling a certain method on hub. However, how to make this work other way around? How do I ensure that hub pushes notifications to only those clients which are authorized to see the updates for specific set of data?

For example:

An Admin client updates a record. SignalR should push this update to other admin clients. However, doing Clients.All.SendAsync will push update to all of the clients. Non-admin clients shouldn't get a notification.

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a RoleManager and then filter `Clients.All` by Id in other to get only a reduced list of admins.

```
var idsWithPermission = roleManager.FindByName("Admins").Users.Select(iur => iur.Id);
var clients = Clients.AllExcept.Where(u =>! idsWithPermission.Contains(u.Id))/*.SomeHelper()*/;
clients.Send("hello world");
```